# Closing the browser with Caliburn micro

Tags: silverlight, caliburn.micro

Just started looking at the amazing framework Caliburn.Micro and was wondering if in a silverlight application the user attempted to close the browser whilst having partially filled in a screen, is there a way to notify the user that the screen has changed data? In order words do not close a screen that has been modified.

I was told that there is no way in a web app to capture the browser closing.

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Caliburn Micro related but could help you and could also be combined with the Framework

http://mark.mymonster.nl/2011/01/30/how-to-cancel-the-closing-of-your-silverlight-application-in-browser-and-out-of-browser

let me know if this helps....